# is it possible to open a webpage as a modal when opened from a another source given certain coding constraints

Tags: javascript, r, html

I have access to two applications.

- Application 1 gives configuration fields that allow you to enter values that will become hyperlinks

  - For example: I can enter `http://www.example.com target=_blank` and it will open then link in a new page.
  - Technically speaking I have some ability to close the tag and start writing my own html in the field but I would rather not if I don't have to. sort of an "html injection" solution might work but as a last resort.
- Application 2 I have full control over the source code and publishing

  - The most frequently used languages in application 2 are html, html5, R, Javascript, C, C++.

I am looking to create a link in application 1, where I have limited control, to open application 2 preferably as a modal, but definitely as some sort of popup type of view for the user.

Tighter integration between the two applications (both from the same company) is coming but it is a future project and we want to create a better user experience now.

Comment: I think that as long as you don't need to share data between the two apps, putting app2 inside an iframe is the easiest method. Then you can use the iframes name as the target of the hyperlink in app1.

Comment: is application1 a website sorta thing? you could try to use a `javascript:open('http://url.com');` maybe?